# composition of uniform substitutions

Tags: formal-languages

Let A be a nonempty alphabet. In a previous question, I asked for the definition of a uniform substitution. Now, my question is this. Is the composition of two substitutions itself a substitution? I have tried hard to prove it, but I failed. Any proof or counterexample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer to my answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610462/formal-definition-of-string-to-term-substitution) and just observe that the composition of two monoid morphisms is a monoid morphism.