# Formal definition of string to string substitution in a string

Tags: definition, formal-languages

This question is related to my previous one, here: [Formal definition of string-to-term substitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610462/formal-definition-of-string-to-term-substitution). Let $A$ be a nonempty alphabet. Also, let $s$ be a nonempty string, and let $t$ be any string, possibly empty. I want to define the notion of substituting $t$ for $s$ in a string. Let me give a few examples. Let our alphabet be $\{a,b,c\}$. Let $s$ be $bab$, and let $t$ be $cc$. In the string $babab$, it becomes $cccc$. As you can see, if there is overlap in a string, we just concatenate them. To give another example, if $s$ is $bb$ and $t$ is $cc$, then the string $bbbb$ becomes $cccccc$. Is it clearer now? My question is, given a string $t$ and a nonempty string $s$, what is the formal definition of the function on $A^*$, the Kleene closure of $A$, that substitutes the string $t$ for $s$ in every string in $A^*$?

Comment: How are you going from $babab$ to $cccc$? I would expect $babbab$ to be $cccc$. Also, I don't think there is any requirement that $s$ and $t$ share an alphabet.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Both $babab$ and $babbab$ go to $cccc$. Basically, if there is an overlap, we still substitute the string, and concatenate.

Comment: @CyclotomicField My question is, what is the rigorous definition of that operation.

Comment: If you're allowing overlap it's not a substitution or string interpolation. You can define such a function on strings with a sliding window algorithm. I'm not sure it would be that interesting though without some context to justify using it.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Okay, maybe it is best not called a substitution. I still would like to know the rigorous definition of that operation.  I do not really have a purpose with that operation, it is just something I am curious about.

Comment: What happens if $s = babcab$?